# Backing up AWS to Dropbox

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, backup, dropbox

Several weeks ago, I had the answer to my question: Install Dropbox for Linux command line, use Andrea Fabrizi's great Dropbox-Uploader script, and finish up with mover.io (which I used to move the files from the app folder, which is not shareable, to a shareable folder).

Sadly, as of the middle of August, mover.io is no longer free. We would prefer not having to pay for their service (especially since we are only copying around 3 MB/day), but I have not yet found an approach that works.

My question: Can you point me to either:

1. a freeware, scriptable approach for copying files from AWS to a shared Dropbox folder?
2. a freeware alternative to mover.io that provides scheduled copying of files from a Dropbox app folder to a Dropbox shared folder?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy/sync files from S3 to a local folder (synced by Dropbox) use the AWS CLI.

- AWS CLI: https://aws.amazon.com/cli/
- AWS CLI S3 Copy Folder: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html
- AWS CLI S3 Sync Folder: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

If you just need to backup S3 to another cloud provider, not necessarily to Dropbox, you should have a look at Google Cloud Storage and their sync service.

- Google Cloud Storage: https://cloud.google.com/storage/
- Google Cloud Storage Transfer Service: https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/

Comment: Andreas - I am marking your reply as the answer because it pointed me in a useful direction. I created a S3 bucket, then updated my script to sync to that bucket instead of Dropbox. I then created a free account on CloudHQ and created a job that one-way syncs from S3 to Dropbox.